# why google analytics showing Goal completion location as "entrance"

Tags: google-analytics

Currently I am facing one issue with google analytics Goal Completion Location. Its showing Goal Completion Location as ‘(entrance)’.

In google analytics it looks like below -

> **Goal Completion Location || Links to xyz.com (Goal 1 Completions) ||    % Links to xyz.com (Goal 1 Completions)**
>
> 1. /default-en.html    ||    831         ||                                  55.59%
> 2. (entrance)          ||    25               ||                             1.67%

What does mean of ‘(entrance)’ in Goal Completion Location and why its displaying in below listing.

How I can remove that from "Goal Completion Location" listing?

Answer (score 9):

I was facing similar problem. GA assigns the event to page user "is currently on". This means you got to fire the event **after** you have send pageview event. If you do it other way around GA assigns the event to wrong(previous) page.

Comment: This is correct.  I just wanted to point out if you are using Google Tag Manager then all you need to do is edit your event tracking tag to fire your Analytics page view tag BEFORE it by editing the 'tag sequencing' section. I changed my goals to events last night and noticed the same (entrance) showing up.  After forcing the page view tag to fire before my event tag everything worked as normal again.

Answer (score 5):

"(entrance)" indicates the page which served as an entry point to your site. It could be that when you set up your URL goal, you didn't have any funnel steps, so when a user arrives at your site, they arrive directly at the goal completion URL. It's not something that can be removed. Rather you would just have to add funnel steps to your goal.